# tslint: namespace and module are disallowed

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces, tslint

I recently got a legacy .ts-file and want to update it.

Two of the warnings say:

`'namespace' and 'module' are disallowed`

and

`The internal 'module' syntax is deprecated, use the 'namespace' keyword instead.`

I read about using standardized ES6-style external modules, but I cannot figure out, how to do this.

My code looks like the following:

```
export namespace MySpace
{
  export module MyModule
  {
    export interface MyInterface
    {
    }

    export class MyClass
    {
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

May anyone give me a hint, how to update this structure to actual style rules?

thank you all a lot in advance!

best regards

mrt

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-namespace/

Comment: thank you, I've found this site already, but I do not know how to interprete it. I'm pretty new to js/ts at all, sorry bout that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *The internal 'module' syntax is deprecated, use the 'namespace' keyword instead.*

This warning from the linter is about `export module MyModule`, because `MyModule` is not a module but a namespace. The keyword that should be used is `namespace`: `export namespace MyModule`.

> *'namespace' and 'module' are disallowed*

This warning from the linter is about `export namespace MySpace`. A top-level `export` implies the file is a module, and [it is a bad practice to use namespaces and modules together](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).

> May anyone give me a hint, how to update this structure to actual style rules?

Do not use `namespace` at all. Here is your code in a module:

```
export interface MyInterface
{
}

export class MyClass
{
}

// …
```

See also: [an introduction to modules from Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

Comment: Namespaces are required to add 'static' members to interfaces. Is there another syntax to use, or do I just need to disable this tslint rule?

Comment: @AndrewArnott I'm unsure what is a "static" member. Maybe it's related to a class? Maybe a simple [declare class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) would be enough?

Comment: Oh interesting. Yes it seems I can `export interface A` *and* `export class A` in the same module, defining static methods (and maybe others?) such that those methods appear on `A.SomeMethod` all while `A` remains to be treated like an interface type by the TypeScript compiler. More testing to do, but this is hopeful.

Comment: @Paleo Why are you suggesting not to use namespaces? just curious

Comment: @Deian Because _TypeScript is JavaScript with syntax for types_… except for `namespace` and `enum`, which don't exist in JS and are not types. IMO these two features should be avoided. Prefer JS modules over namespaces, and unions over enums.

Comment: @Paleo Enums are a critical infrastructure man ... but thank you for the perspective!